# Slash doesn't work in matching query using regexp in Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, indexing, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

[In the official Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#query-dsl-regexp-query) there is written `Any reserved character can be escaped with a backslash "\*" including a literal backslash character: "\\"`.

Can you explain me why query like this

```
{
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "regexp": {
                                        "path": ".*test\/test.txt.*"
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "user_id": 1
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
```

doesn't find index like this

```
{
                "_index": "pictures",
                "_type": "picture",
                "_id": "wiskQ2kBi923Omj4U",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "tag": [],
                    "text": "some text",
                    "path": "test/test.txt"
                }
            }
```

Comment: You don't need to escape a `/`, do you?

Comment: @MatBailie that's engine dependent. in some engines you need to escape. however not sure which engine OP is using

Comment: Can you add the mapping of the index as well?

Comment: @NishantSaini I can't paste it to the edited post so I pasted it here https://pastebin.com/MmwmVDU0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `path` is analysed field the regex wont match it. The reason is that `test/test.txt` get tokenised into two different terms: `test` and `test.txt`. Since `path` has a sub-field **`keyword`** of data type `keyword` which will index `test/test.txt` as it is, you should query on this field i.e. `path.keyword`.

Use the below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "path.keyword": ".*test/test.txt.*"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "user_id": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note the importance of `.*` at the beginning and end of the regex (`".*test/test.txt.*"`). I didn't get any matches without them.

Comment: Thank you for calling out the keyword bit specifically! I was banging my head against the wall because I was still getting some matches without it but any time I would try to regexp match a symbol like `=` I would get 0 results